# comparing value from inputfield with django model data in js function

Tags: javascript, django

I have already made an app that allows me to study. It contains multiple test with multiple question with one correct answer each.

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def get_questions(self):
        return self.question_set.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Question(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def get_answer(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent')
    def __str__(self):
         return self.text
```

I made JS funtion that compare user answer from input field with correct answer put in html

```
function PointsCounter(){
   var points = 0;
   const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.question-container');
   Array.from(elements).forEach((element, index) => {
      var CorrectAnswer = (((element.querySelector('div form p')).innerHTML).toLowerCase()).trim();
    
    var UserAnswer = (((element.querySelector('div form p input')).value).toLowerCase()).trim();

   if(UserAnswer == CorrectAnswer){
   points++;
   }})
    document.getElementById("points").innerHTML=points;

                    
    }
```

Instead of putting correct answer in my html code:

```
<p id="ans" hidden>{{ question.parent.all.last }}</p>
```

I'd like to compare user answer with answer from database, but I do not know how to achieve it.

I mean, i'd like to pass correct answer to js function to disallow user to check answer by  inspecting html code of page. How can I make it ?

Comment: If you pass the correct answer to JS, the user could check the JS code too. Why not make the job on the server side inside views.py? It's the only way to be sure that nobody can see the correct answer. In addition, you will be able to keep track of the correct answers and the number of attempts of each user before getting it right.

Comment: I would write up a REST endpoint and make a request with ajax sending what user has picked with the data and check whether the answer was correct or not on the backend.

another solution can be to encode the correct answer when rending the html and then encode the user answer and compare the two values.. this however makes it hard for the user to figure out the correct answer but not impossible